# How to get OnCheckedChangeListener in RadioGroup

Tags: android

RadioGroup provide method "set()" for OnCheckedChangeListener, but not "get()". But my module must in some way get OnCheckedChangeListener of RadioGroup and wrap it with my listener, which provide tracking of behavior for customer. How can I get this OnCheckedChangeListener listener without asking user of my library to provide it explicitly as parameter?

Sample of problem:

we can implement method:

```
void wrapMyRadioGroup(RadioGroup group,OnCheckedChangeListener listener){
     group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SomeCompositeListener(listener));
}
```

but can't some like this:

```
void wrapMyRadioGroup(RadioGroup group){
     group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SomeCompositeListener(group.getOnCheckedChangeListener()));
}
```

And,as you can gues, we need last one.

P.S.

I've found solution with reflection.

```
  private void trackRadioGroup(RadioGroup radioGroup){
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = null;
    try {
        Field field = radioGroup.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOnCheckedChangeListener");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(radioGroup);
        if(value !=null){
            listener = (RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener)value;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SomeCompositeListener(listener));
}
```

Thanks all for understanding and rates...

Comment: Are you looking for get RadioButton checked from RadioGroup?

Comment: post your code what you are tried.

Comment: I am looking for approach to capture existing listener in  RadioGroup, to wrap it with code of our library, and set back again.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.cancle_booking_radio_group);

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
            int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // perform your action here
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // perform your action here
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // perform your action here
                    break;
                case 3:
                   // perform your action here
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // perform your action here
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: no. I need capture listener which was before and your code removed this listener at all